# what does 'hash' property mean in webpack plugin stats

Tags: javascript, plugins, webpack

I've got a simple plugin for webpack

```
function () {
    this.plugin("done", function (stats) {
        //some stuff to do
    }
}
```

What I wonder is what does `stats.hash` property mean in the `stats` object? Is it a unified hash for all output chunks? Can I learn if my new built chunks differ from previous build from this hash?

Comment: what exactly you want to do with it ? I guess it is being generated from following code https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Compilation.js#L1095

Comment: don't think so it is documented anywhere, need to conclude from source code only